# count of matching words of two text columns in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

i have a table , which has two columns id and text. This is what data i have:

```
id  text
765 hi how are you
876 John made $57.
743 apple is my favourite fruit.
435 mango is not my favorite fruit.
892 this is my favourite movie
```

have input column as slicer,in which i can choose any one id.for eg: 743

```
-765
-876
-**743**
-435
-892
```

I need the output, in which it would show the id ,text,number of words matching of the selected id from slicer with all the other ids:

```
id  text                             matching words
743 apple is my favourite fruit.       5
765 hi how are you                     0
876 John made $57.                     0
435 mango is not my favorite fruit.    4
892 this is my favourite movie         3
```

Comment: OK, this needs to be done in DAX as PQ would require a cartesian join which is 16m rows. It isn't a massive number but it obviously doesn't scale if you add more rows.

Comment: can you tell how????

Comment: Does it need to be case-sensitive?

Comment: no..............

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head. Let me have a think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have a solution but I'm not convinced it is the most elegant.

[image]

Thanks to the following resource for a text.split function in DAX https://www.excelnaccess.com/text-split-using-dax/.

Create a base table named Table as follows:

[image]

Create 2 calculated tables with the following code.

```
New Table1 = 
VAR myvalues =
     ADDCOLUMNS ( 'Table', "Paths", TRIM( SUBSTITUTE ( SUBSTITUTE( [text],".","") , " ", "|" ) ))

RETURN 
SELECTCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (
            myvalues,
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, PATHLENGTH ( [Paths] ) ),
                "@word", PATHITEM ( [Paths], [Value], TEXT )
            )
        ),
        "id", [id],
        "word", [@word],
        "text", [text]

    )
New Table2 = 
VAR myvalues =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( 'Table', "Paths", TRIM( SUBSTITUTE ( SUBSTITUTE( [text],".","") , " ", "|" ) ))

RETURN 
SELECTCOLUMNS (
        GENERATE (
            myvalues,
            ADDCOLUMNS (
                GENERATESERIES ( 1, PATHLENGTH ( [Paths] ) ),
                "@word", PATHITEM ( [Paths], [Value], TEXT )
            )
        ),
        "id", [id],
        "word", [@word],
        "text", [text]

    )
```

Drag New Table 1 [id] to a slicer

Drag New Table 2 [id] and [text] to a table.

Create a measure as follows and drag it into the table.

```
Matching Words = IF(ISFILTERED('New Table1'[id]), COUNTROWS('New Table2')+0, 0)
```

Create a relationship between word and word as follows:

[image]

That should be everything.

Comment: thanks a lot.can you please add screenshot of the code of the calculated tables

Comment: can we sort them by count of matching words

Comment: instead of matching words can we find the percentage

Comment: You mean percentage of matching words? If so, that's trivial. Just change the measure to a percent.

Comment: just take into account matching numbers like 57 in this case.

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe ask a new question with some details.

Comment: i am asking incase of matching words, does take into account the numbers too.,

Comment: Yes, it classes everything between spaces as a word. The only punctuation I removed were full stops. You should be able to adjust the code to your needs now the heavy lifting is done.

Comment: hi , is there anyway we can search in slicer for id . I was unable to do.

Comment: Open a separate question and someone should be able to help.